# Can we Set a page number in CSS for print only a certain page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, print-preview

I want to print a single page through CSS or javascript. How can I assign a page number in CSS or Javascript?. IF I press a ctrl+P it only previews that page in print preview?. I am using chrome.

```
@page{
margin:0.5cm;
size:portrait;
}
```